# Import of client scenarios

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I import a file to update the client, but when I go to the AR303000 screen, an error appears.

[image: here is the error attached]

please someone to tell me what is wrong, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message implies that you are importing `Customer ID` that already exists in the database. It is a duplicate validation error. Customer ID is used as a key field and key fields must be unique in database.

If I were to import a customer with `Customer ID` ABARTENDE, I would expect this error because a customer with that ID already exists in the system:
[image]

EDIT:
Issue was duplicate ID in customization. Was confused with the import scenario.

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, the error was not due to the import scenarios; if not when two projects with the same screens are published, the error appears.

Comment: Although I put levels on it, the same error keeps coming up, what do I do?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxqlC.png

Comment: You likely have duplicate IDs in the ASPX customization coming from different customizations. You're right that it is unrelated to import scenario.

Comment: That's right, I do not know how to solve this problem, although I put levels, I still get an error, I need advice.

Comment: In customization project editor, for both projects use menu File->Edit XML, review ID fields ID="xyz" to make sure there are no duplicates. I'm not 100% sure the error is ID related but there is items with identical key somewhere. Sometimes programmers don't change the default ID and end up with 2 customizations having same ID which is problematic because they are used as key so must be unique.

Comment: I already solved them, ID: PXLayoutRule1 had the same id in another cutomizado, I had to change the name and it worked, thank you very much.